# Codeigniter - variable from model to view

Tags: codeigniter

I have form that contain input and pass it to model. it works

```
$id = $this->input->post('searchtestname'); // searchtestname is the input from view.
```

now my question is, how can I use `$id` to the view as displaying the result?

(eg: `` Displaying result of `$id`: //table result// ``)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont understand what's going on in your question but, just from the topic:

```
$model_data = $someModel->getSomeDataFromIt($id); //load data from some model - remember to inicialize it first 
$data = array('model_data' => $model_data);
$this->load->view('main_view', $data);
```

and build your result table upon the recieved data